# Connecting two modules

Tags: angularjs

I do have two modules: app & myApp.I am trying to connect two modules by defining myApp as dependent module to app like this :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['myModule','ui.router']);
```

Whenever I add 'myModule' as above i get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: As per the first line of your question you have two module. **app** and **myApp**.
But in your code there is var app = angular.module('**app**', ['**myModule**','ui.router']); May be you have variable name mistake problem.

Comment: make sure myModule code/file is added before you are injecting it as dependency

Comment: Your error says **You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it**. So you need to check you misspelled or not loaded your module js

Comment: @AbhilashPA that is incorrect. Modules can be created in whatever order you want.

Comment: I am pretty sure no misspelling error. variable name is also correct and yes i did add the myModule file to my index file. Still getting a problem. Can someone help me with example in connecting two different modules?